# Does MongoDB require me to manually run mongod in shell?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating node.js app with MongoDB database. I am using mongoose module.

```
  mongoose
   .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
   })
```

While running code above, the connection used to establish on it's own. Also when I opened MongoDB Compass and filled the connection string it just worked.
Then I used mongod in PowerShell to test behaviour of my app when I disconnect database. I opened connection, ran the app and closed connection with ^C.
Then when I wanted to run my app like I used to before, it didn't work and now I have to always open PowerShell and start mongod before using Mongo Compass or connecting via app.
Moreover data from the "myapp" database disappeared completely.

I am just curious what happened.

Comment: yes, mongo must be running for Mongoose to connect to it

Comment: I have found that autostart MongoDB uses different database than mongod, that's why my files weren't vissible in Compass.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a mongodb Service in background.

Refer [THIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/157705/how-can-i-run-mongod-in-the-background-on-unix-mac-osx)

```
service mongod status
service mongod start
service mongod stop
```